# php socket server works only on localhost but not live server

Tags: php, sockets, server

I have hosting domain godaddy and i enabled socket module, but dose not work 
this code works only in localhost when i upload it in server it does not work.

**code server.php**

```
<?php
// set some variables
$host = '150.113.178.20';
$port = 5000;

 if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $host , $port) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";

echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

//start loop to listen for incoming connections
while (true) 
{
    //Accept incoming connection - This is a blocking call
    $client =  socket_accept($sock);

    //display information about the client who is connected
    if(socket_getpeername($client , $address , $port))
    {
        echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
    }

    //read data from the incoming socket
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024000);

    $response = "OK .. $input";

    // Display output  back to client
    socket_write($client, $response);
}
```

when i execute server.php script in ssh no problem

[image]

but when i write from CMD :

[image]

Error log file

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: You sure its that IP?

Comment: here code and pic i gave u just an example, but yes im sure in my code IP address is correct.

Comment: i would suggest adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of your code to see if there is any errors , and probably it's the port, try another one ..

Comment: im executing server.php in terminal so error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1); they useless, i tried many ports but the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found that The code is correct
Godaddy does not open custom ports.
The code does not work because have a different security policy localhost than GoDaddy (or other hosting website).

Comment: So how can we create a TCP Server in Godaddy cloud